# Laravel: Save Base64 .png file to public folder from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I send a png image file to controller in base64 via Ajax. I've already test and sure that controller has received id but still can't save it to public folder.

**Here is my controller**

```
public function postTest() {
        $data = Input::all();

        //get the base-64 from data
        $base64_str = substr($data->base64_image, strpos($data->base64_image, ",")+1);

        //decode base64 string
        $image = base64_decode($base64_str);
        $png_url = "product-".time().".png";
        $path = public_path('img/designs/' . $png_url);

        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);
        // I've tried using 
        // $result = file_put_contents($path, $image); 
        // too but still not working

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
        );
        return Response::json( $response  );
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Intervention Image gets binary data using file_get_content function:
Reference : [Image::make](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/make)

Your controller should be look like this:

```
public function postTest() {
    $data = Input::all();
    $png_url = "product-".time().".png";
    $path = public_path().'img/designs/' . $png_url;

    Image::make(file_get_contents($data->base64_image))->save($path);     
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
    );
    return Response::json( $response  );
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
         $file = base64_decode($request['image']);
         $safeName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
         $success = file_put_contents(public_path().'/uploads/'.$safeName, $file);
         print $success;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$data = Input::all();
$png_url = "perfil-".time().".jpg";
$path = public_path() . "/img/designs/" . $png_url;
$img = $data['fileo'];
$img = substr($img, strpos($img, ",")+1);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$success = file_put_contents($path, $data);
print $success ? $png_url : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Comment: in '$img = $data['fileo'];' what does $data['fileo'] represent?

Answer (score 5):

This is an easy mistake.

You are using public_path incorrectly. It should be:

```
$path = public_path() . "/img/designs/" . $png_url;
```

Also, I would avoid your method of sending the image. Look at a proper upload in a form and use Laravel's Input::file method.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I always use public_path() like this and it's work fine. And i think the problem is Input::file method too. So now i'm give up using it :P. check my answer!

Comment: The path is not a problem and it's not required either, only `$path = "/img/designs/" . $png_url` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is:

```
public function postTest() {
        $data = Input::all();

        //get the base-64 from data
        $base64_str = substr($data->base64_image, strpos($data->base64_image, ",")+1);

        //decode base64 string
        $image = base64_decode($base64_str);
        Storage::disk('local')->put('imgage.png', $image);
        $storagePath = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
        echo $storagePath.'imgage.png'; 
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
        );
        return Response::json( $response  );
}
```

Comment: how we can add a path input method. the filename should be dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Store or save base64 images in the public folder image and return file path.

```
    $folderPath = public_path() . '/' . 'images/';
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $uniqid = uniqid();
    $file = $folderPath . $uniqid . '.' . $image_type;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
    return $file;
```

Answer (score 1):

what am i doing is using basic way

```
$file = base64_decode($request['profile_pic']);
            $folderName = '/uploads/users/';
            $safeName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
            $destinationPath = public_path() . $folderName;
            file_put_contents(public_path().'/uploads/users/'.$safeName, $file);

           //save new file path into db
            $userObj->profile_pic = $safeName;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Input::all()` returns an `array` of inputs so you have following:

```
$data = Input::all();
```

Now your `$data` is an array not an object so you are trying to access the image as an object like:

```
$data->base64_image
```

So, it's not working. You should try using:

```
$image = $data['base64_image'];
```

Since it's (`base64_image`) accessible from `$_POST` then `Input::file('base64_image')` won't work because `Input::file('base64_image')` checks the `$_FILES` array and it's not there in your case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'm using your method with  `$result = file_put_contents($path, $image); ` Now png image is built. But file is unreadable. Is `$data['base64_image']` already a saveable file?

Comment: Probably Not, did you use `$base64_str`?

Comment: Yes,but still unreadable. FYI, base64_image look like this "data:image/png:base64,iVBORwOkG.....".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for the file upload from base_64.

```
    public static function uploadBase64File(Request $request, $requestName = 'imageData', $fileName = null, $uploadPath = 'uploads/images/')
    {
        try {
                $requestFileData = $request->$requestName;

                // decode the base64 file
                $file = base64_decode(preg_replace(
                    '#^data:([^;]+);base64,#',
                    '',
                    $request->input($requestName)
                ));

                if (in_array($file, ["", null, ' '])) {
                    return null;
                }

                //handle base64 encoded images here
                if ($fileName == null) {
                    $fileName = Str::random(10);
                }

                $extension = '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($requestFileData, 0, strpos($requestFileData, ';')))[1])[1];

                $filePath = $uploadPath . '' . $fileName . '' . $extension;

                // dd($extension);
                if (!File::exists(public_path($uploadPath))) {
                    File::makeDirectory(public_path($uploadPath), 0777, true);
                }

                // dd($filePath);
                $ifImageUploadSuccessful = File::put(public_path($filePath), $file);

                if (!$ifImageUploadSuccessful) {
                    return null;
                }

                return '/' . $filePath;
            // throw new Exception("Unable To upload Image");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // dd($e);
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets improve your code, shall we?!

**Using following code gives you ability of:**

1. Get files extensions dynamically instead of statically writing them
2. Define where you like to store them (I provided both ways for you to choose from)

```php
// Your incoming base64 image from form
$image_64 = $request->input('image');

// Get extension
$extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ';')))[1])[1];
$replace = substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ',')+1);
$image = str_replace($replace, '', $image_64);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);

// Give image a name
$imageName = Str::random(10).'.'.$extension;

// Store in public folder (or public_html in live server)
file_put_contents(public_path('images/'.$imageName), base64_decode($image));

// If you want to store in storage folder use this line instead
// Storage::disk('public')->put('images/'.$imageName, base64_decode($image));

// Store image name in DB
$model->image = 'images/'.$imageName;
```

*Happy coding.*

Answer (score -1):

I'v done it!!

I replaced 
`$data->base64_image` to  `$_POST['base64_image']` and then  use 
`$result = file_put_contents($path, $image);`
instead of `Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);`

But this doesn't look like a laravel ways. I you have another way that look more elegant please tell me!

Comment: Your problem is `$data->base64_image`, it should be `$data['base64_image']` instead, check my answer.