# How to move a base64 decoded image in Laravel (to directory)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a form, where I upload an image in base64encode.

```
<input type=hidden value=.....(base64encode string) />
```

In Laravel's method (where I handle input data) I have

```
$data = Request::all(); // get all input data
$img = base64_decode($data["img"]); // my decoded image
```

How can I move this decoded image in (any) directory? In Laravel's manual I've read about

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath);
```

But I don't know how to use it in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: Save Base64 .png file to public folder from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785940/laravel-save-base64-png-file-to-public-folder-from-controller)

Answer (score 2):

**If anybody is still looking this is my solution**
I was looking for a way to optimize images locally (in the browser) and then upload it;
This is how I receive it in my laravel app :

```
Route::post('myroute', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $data){

   $base64_str = substr($data->image, strpos($data->image, ",")+1); // get the image code
   $image = base64_decode($base64_str); // decode the image
   file_put_contents('/path/newImage.JPG',$image); // move the image to the desired path with desired name and extension  

)};
```

Comment: what if you have multiple images?

Comment: if you have multiple images the `$data` will be an array so you can just loop through theme

Comment: the `$data->image` is the one will be an array, if you have in your html `<input type="file" name="image[]" >` , so wrap that code in  `foreach($data->image as $image){ }` and replace the `$data->image` up there with `$image`

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageName = rand(11111, 99999) . '_' . time() . '.jpg';
$path = 'uploads/'.$directory_name."/". $imageName;
Storage::disk('local')->put($path, base64_decode($image));
```

try this, you can change/create disk from your config/filesystem