# Laravel how to save the base64 data image?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I know how to save a normal file from `HTML <form>` with `type="file"`

maybe I can do that
`$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');`

Actually, I using a Js package about a `image upload & drop & crop`

HTML / Blade

```html
<form action="{{route('avatar.update')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="avatar">
<div class="slim rounded-2xl "
      data-label="Select your Avatar"
      data-size="400,400"
      data-ratio="1:1">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" >
</div>
<button type="submit"> Update </button>
</form>
```

when the form submit with selected a image.

`$request->file('avatar')` = null

Because I check when the submit, the `input('avatar')` will be changed to `type="hidden"`, so I can use `$request->file('avatar')`

Then....
`dd($request->all());` I got

```json
[
  "_token" => "od91HbEuWSbgx5gqfaNOeHQIC8qUBMumzf7u4Dvr",
  "avatar" => "{
      "server":null,
      "meta":{},
    
      "input":{"name":"ccc.png","type":"image/png","size":1412200,"width":2860,"height":1440,"field":null},
    
      "output":{"name":"ccc.png",
                "type":"image/png",
                "width":400,"height":400,
                "image":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUCC....etc"},
      
      "actions":{"rotation":null,"crop":{"x":710,"y":0,"height":1440,"width":1440,"type":"auto"},"size":{"width":400,"height":400},"filters":{"sharpen":0},"minSize":{"width":0,"height":0}}
    
    }"
]
```

I get this image is base64 format? how can I to save it?

I try `base64_decode` but not work.
`$avatar = base64_decode($request->input('avatar'));`

fixed the problem from @gguney!

the main problem is I forgot to json_decode the avatar input!

controller code now

```php
        $image = json_decode($request->input('avatar'))->output->image;
        $imageName = time() . 'ava.png';

        $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
        Storage::disk('temp_avatar')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Save Base64 .png file to public folder from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785940/laravel-save-base64-png-file-to-public-folder-from-controller)

Comment: @gguney Thanks, But I had try that answer before create this question. Actually can't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you share your controller code?

Comment: Sure, I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
json_decode($request->input('avatar'))->output->image
```

Comment: Error:Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Can you try again? If not can you share dd json_decode($request->input('avatar')) ?

Comment: Thansk, But still not can, dd srceen:  https://ibb.co/N9S1233

Comment: Check it again please

Comment: Thanks so much @gguney , I can got the base64 content. But if I save it, I will got a problem image file. I will updated the topic content for u now

Comment: I think your base64 question answered then. You can mark it as an answer and create a new question about it. That's different question. And why do you need base64 thing? Just use file from your request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242897/discussion-between-gguney-and-scxsk0992).